# Android studio codes are showing red color. But it runs successfully

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

All codes in my project will be in red color . But i can run my project successfully. i updated andriod 
 studio as well as i clean , rebuild the project. The errors are still existing there. Can anyone help to 
 solve the problem.

Comment: just try to re-sync gradle and if does not work then do invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Open File menu > Invalidate Caches / Restart.. option and click on the Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: just delete .gradle directory and rebuild the project if not solve then go to the File menu > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: @ShahnawazKhan I did it. But still error exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solution 1:

try sync gradle

```
File -> Sync Project With gradle Files
```

If not work, follow solution 2.

> Solution 2:

Just remove  dependencies inside `dependencies{}` section and sync

then back to all dependencies and sync

**Step 1**

```
//1. Remove all dependencies 
//2. Sync
dependencies {

}
```

**Step 2**

```
//1. back to all dependencies (Re-Add) 
//2. Sync
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   ......
   ......
}
```

One day I face same problem and I solve them by second tricks..